# Why does SWIG crash Python when linked to gtkglext?

Tags: python, scripting, swig

Anything I link to gtkglext using SWIG crashes Python on exit.  Why does this crash?

test.i:

```
%module test
%{
void test() { printf("Test.\n"); }
%}
void test();
```

Session:

```
$ swig -python test.i

$ g++ -I/usr/include/python2.6 -shared -fPIC -o _test.so test_wrap.c -lpython2.6

$ python -c 'import test; test.test()'
Test.

$ g++ -I/usr/include/python2.6 -shared -fPIC -o _test.so test_wrap.c -lpython2.6 `pkg-config --libs gtkglext-1.0`

$ python -c 'import test; test.test()'
Test.
Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas?  Thanks...

Comment: What happens when you run it under gdb? What about a trace using 'python -v'? Does the core dump occur without calling test.test()? Also, try using a setup.py file to build the extensions, so Python itself manages the compiler flags and required libraries and library order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init gtk properly.

```
$ cat test.i 
%module test
%{
void test() { printf("Test.\n"); }
%}
void test();
$ swig -python test.i ; gcc -I/usr/include/python2.5 -shared -fPIC -o _test.so test_wrap.c -lpython2.5 `pkg-config --libs gtkglext-1.0`
$ python -c 'import test; test.test()'
Test.
Segmentation fault
$ python -c 'import gtk; import test; test.test()'
Test.
```

Comment: That does indeed seem to fix it but can you explain why? I'm not calling any GTK functions, this makes no sense to me.

Comment: `import gtk` calls some init functions.

Comment: Clearly, but why would I need to call any GTK init functions if I'm not _using_ GTK, only linking to it?  Does some code get called automatically when a library is simply linked?